# How to visualize Pyfst transducers via dot files

Tags: python-3.x, dot, transducer, openfst, fst

I am learning how to create transducers with Pyfst and I am trying to visualize the ones I create. The ultimate goal is to be able to write the transducers to dot files and see them in Graphviz.

I took a sample code to see how to visualize the following acceptor.

```
a = fst.Acceptor()
a.add_arc(0, 1, 'x', 0.1)
a[1].final = -1
a.draw()
```

When I use draw(), which comes with the package, I get an error:

```
File "/Users/.../tests.py", line 42, in <module>
a.draw()

File "_fst.pyx", line 816, in fst._fst.StdVectorFst.draw
(fst/_fst.cpp:15487)

File "/Users/.../venv-3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

If I try to write the above mentioned acceptor to .dot via this:

```
def fst_dot(dot_object, filename):
path, file = split(filename)
new_path = join(dot_files_folder_path, path)
if not os.path.exists(new_path):
    os.makedirs(new_path)
if hasattr(dot_object, 'dotFormat'):
    draw_string = dot_object.dotFormat()
else:
    draw_string = dot_object.draw()
open(join(dot_files_folder_path, filename + ".dot"), "w").write(draw_string)
```

then also I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/...tests.py", line 43, in <module>
fst_dot(a, 'acceptor')

File "/Users/...tests.py", line 22, in fst_dot
draw_string = dot_object.draw()

File "_fst.pyx", line 816, in fst._fst.StdVectorFst.draw
(fst/_fst.cpp:15487)

File "/Users/.../venv-3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

So, both errors look the same - there is some kind of an issue with draw().
On the pyfst site it says that draw is used for dot format representation of the transducer.

I can't understand how to fix the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using OSX and PyCharm.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using Python2 to see if that helps at all.

However, I think you'll be better off using the Python bindings that are included with OpenFST 1.5+.  That library also has the ability to write to GraphViz `.dot` files.  There is documentation available here:

http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/PythonExtension

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try, however my project requires to be written in Python 3. I'm still trying to find a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you `fstdraw` command from openfst.

after `a.write('tmp.fst')` in python.
`$ fstdraw tmp.fst > tmp.dot` in shell.

**EDIT:**

Finally, I found that UFAL's forked pyfst works fine with python3.
https://github.com/UFAL-DSG/pyfst